# c# /optimize compiler option (VS2012)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, compiler-construction, csc

If an assembly is built with `/optimize-` (that's a dash/minus sign at the end) passed to `Csc.exe` does it get optimized or not?

What's the difference between the following three options:

```
/optimize
/optimize+
/optimize-
```

I don't find the MSDN article too helpful..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t0hfscdc

Comment: Quote: "/optimize also tells the common language runtime to optimize code at runtime".  What *exactly* is unclear about that?

Comment: @HansPassant The docs never explicitly states what the +/- flag does.  Perhaps optimize- would do some optimizations, but not as many, a "partial optimization".  That's a sensible (but incorrect) guess.

Comment: @HansPassant: I suspect that the documentation for `/optimize` is entirely incorrect, actually - surely it's telling the *compiler* to optimize the code, rather than the CLR. I would also say it's not entirely clear whether `/optimize` is equivalent to `/optimize+`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the way of *explicitly* saying that optimizations are off.  It's just the same as omitting the parameter entirely.  The option exists so that you can make it clear to the reader (perhaps in a batch script) that you intentionally don't want the optimizations, rather than having a reader think you simply forgot to add the parameter.